# how to load and save qsettings in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want qtsettings to load and save a profile class object as shown in the following list

```
[profiles]
[profilename1]
data
[profilename2]
data
```

Comment: why -1 ! without commenting is a disaster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QSettings settings("myapp.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
settings.beginGroup("profiles");
settings.beginGroup("profilename1");
settings.setValue("value", QString("data"));
settings.endGroup();
settings.beginGroup("profilename2");
settings.setValue("value", QString("data"));
settings.endGroup();
settings.endGroup();
```

Comment: yea I know that but I don't have the name profilename1, it should be generated itself. check my previous question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36797329/getting-the-profile-setting-using-qt-settings

Comment: @andreahmed: try explain in other words what you want.

Comment: I have a class profile and it has some members. I want to save it to the settings and load it back. but when i use the code that is posted in the other thread. it doesn't load the profile class correctly, it loads all the childern of the qsettings

Comment: @andreahmed: see my answer on your previos question

Comment: can you solve this problem please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36839364/profile-settings-for-qtsettings