# Profile Settings for QTsettings

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a profile which consists of Method names and its relation between each profile

```
void Method::loadFrom(Settings &set, bool ownGroup)
{
    Settings s("profiles.ini");
    s.beginGroup("Profiles");
    foreach (const QString &group, s.childGroups()) {
        s.beginGroup(group);
        Profile *profile = new Profile();
        profile->setObjectName(group);
        profile->load(s);
        s.endGroup();

        m_currentProfileManager->m_Profiles << profile;
    }
    EraObject::staticLoadFrom(set, this, ownGroup);

}

void Method::saveTo(Settings &set, bool ownGroup, bool force)
{
    Settings s("profiles.ini");
    s.beginGroup("Profiles");
    foreach(Profile * profile, m_currentProfileManager->m_Profiles) {
        s.beginGroup(profile->profilename());
        profile->save(s);
        s.endGroup();
    }
    s.endGroup();
    s.sync();

    EraObject::staticSaveTo(set, this, ownGroup, force);

}
```

Now the current profile is

```
[Profiles]

    %20Default\Ta=@Variant(\0\0\0\x87\x41\xa0\0\0)
    %20Default\Te=@Variant(\0\0\0\x87\x42@\0\0)
    %20Default\Texp=@Variant(\0\0\0\x87\x42\x18\0\0)
    %20Default\dirty=0
    %20Default\lim1=@Variant(\0\0\0\x87\0\0\0\0)
    %20Default\lim2=@Variant(\0\0\0\x87\0\0\0\0)
    %20Default\objectName=" Default"
    %20Default\offset=@Variant(\0\0\0\x87\0\0\0\0)
    %20Default\profilename=" Default"
    yg\Ta=@Variant(\0\0\0\x87\x41\xa0\0\0)
    yg\Te=@Variant(\0\0\0\x87\x42@\0\0)
    yg\Texp=@Variant(\0\0\0\x87\x42\x18\0\0)
    yg\dirty=1
    yg\lim1=@Variant(\0\0\0\x87\0\0\0\0)
    yg\lim2=@Variant(\0\0\0\x87\0\0\0\0)
    yg\objectName=yg
    yg\offset=@Variant(\0\0\0\x87\0\0\0\0)
    yg\profilename=yg
    yu\Ta=@Variant(\0\0\0\x87\x41\xa0\0\0)
    yu\Te=@Variant(\0\0\0\x87\x42@\0\0)
    yu\Texp=@Variant(\0\0\0\x87\x42\x18\0\0)
    yu\dirty=1
    yu\lim1=@Variant(\0\0\0\x87\0\0\0\0)
    yu\lim2=@Variant(\0\0\0\x87\0\0\0\0)
    yu\objectName=yu
    yu\offset=@Variant(\0\0\0\x87\0\0\0\0)
    yu\profilename=yu
```

I have for each Method name a profile, here its `default` and `yu`.

I would like for each `method name` to generate its own profile and load it and save it.
Currently all the methods load the `same profile` settings which is wrong.

I want each method to have its own set of profiles.

```
Method is just a qstring.
```

Comment: "I want each method to have its own set of profiles." Wonderful. So just do it then. What was your question?

Comment: how would I define that using qsettings ?

Comment: There are many ways. A simple one would be to open a group for each method.

Comment: so I should write s.begin(methodname)?

Comment: It's up to you exactly what you do, but that would be one way of doing it, yes :)